# Why $ \mathbb R$ with topology generated by base of form [a,b) is not topological vector space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

> Why $ \mathbb R$  with topology generated  by base of form [a,b) is not topological vector space?

Topological Vector space:Suppose $\tau$ is topology on vector space X such that

1) every singleton is closed

2) both vector space operation is continuous

I can show that every singleton of R with given topology is closed but how to not continous to conclude result

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Hint: look at the operation $-$ (negation).

Comment: The preimage of $[0,1)$ by multiplication is the set $A=\{(x;y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_l:\ 0\leq xy<1\}$. All open sets containing $(0;-1)\in A$ contain some basis element $(x,y)\times [z,t)$ containing $(0;-1)$, and this contains points $(r;-1)$ with $r>0$. But $(r,-1)\notin A$. So, $A$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_l$.

Comment: Echoing @MeesdeVries's comment, note that $-{1 \over n} \not\to 0$.

Comment: There are *three* vector space operations: addition $V \times V \to V$, negation $V \to V$ and scalar multiplication $\Bbb F \times V \to \Bbb F$ over the topological field $\Bbb F$ (most commonly reals or complex numbers, sometimes rationals, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct way is to note that $\Bbb R_l$ is not even a topological group w.r.t. $+$, as the map $f(x)=-x$ is not continuous: $[0,1)$ is open but $f^{-1}[[0,1)) = (-1,0]$ is not open, as $0$ is not an interior point of it (all basic neighbourhoods of $0$, which are of the form $[0,r)$, "stick out"). This doesn't use the scalar multiplication, so it's irrelevant over what field we're working.

An indirect way is to note that $\Bbb R_l$ is not locally compact (all compact subsets are at most countable, even) but as a $1$-dimensional vector space (over $\Bbb R$) it would have to be locally compact.

Also, $\Bbb R_l$ is totally disconnected, while all real or complex vector spaces are even path-connected.